# Flutter web and tflite machine learning custom model

Tags: flutter, machine-learning, image-classification, tflite

i am facing trouble integrating my custom trained artificial intelligence image classifier model in my flutter web application. i have already converted and saved the model in tflite and labels.txt file, but tflite package documentation only show support for android & ios. is there any way to integrate tflite into my flutter web app or should i look for some other solution

tflite,label.txt,image picker from gallery

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.